# PDF figure not compiling

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf, texshop, includegraphics

I know that this a common request in this forum but I've tried all suggestions of previous posts unsuccessfully. I apologize if it's still obvious.

So basically, I am trying to compile a pdf image on my LaTex documents using TexShop editor but the image doesn't appear and I have no error warning : simply a blank zone.

Here is my usual coding :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]

    \captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,size=footnotesize}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{myfigure}
    \caption{This is the caption text}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
    
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Could please someone help me to understand why is it happening ?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: If I add `\documentclass{article}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` at the appropriate places, I do get the picture. What about you?

Comment: make an example people can test, remove unused packages, add `\documentclass{article}` , use  `example-image` which is available for tests, and show the log that you get

Comment: Are you using `draft` option to your document class or anything like that?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have just changed the image uploaded : it's no longer a pdf but a jpeg and now it's working : I haven't changed anything in my code despite the image format... Have you ever encountered this problem before ?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: Then your image pdf file is somehow corrupt or you need to upgrade your LaTeX installation.  Try `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{skip=0.5\baselineskip,size=footnotesize}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck.pdf}
\caption{This is the caption text}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}` . You should get desired result with warning regarding to layouts package.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who tried to help me : it was a strange issue surely related to TexShop. The problem was in the LaTex editor itself since I've just tried to re-install it and test another pdf file : it worked immediately !